# Score not increasing with contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm struggling to increase my score when an object passes by another object.

I've tried to change the `contactTestBitMask` with mixed results Would anyone know what is wrong with my code?

I've removed the majority of the code that isn't required, if anyone would like to play around with it.

```
import SpriteKit

var contact = SKSpriteNode()
var birdTexture1 = SKTexture()
var scoreTexture1 = SKTexture()
var birds = SKNode()
var moveAndRemoveBirds = SKAction()
var moving = SKNode()

let scoreCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 3
let contact2Category: UInt32 = 1 << 2
let crowCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 2

var scoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
var score = NSInteger()
var highScoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
var highScore = NSInteger()


class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    self.addChild(moving)
    moving.addChild(birds)

    birdTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "crow")
    birdTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    var distanceToMoveBird = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2 * birdTexture1.size().width);
    var moveBirds = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMoveBird, y:0, duration:NSTimeInterval(0.0040 * distanceToMoveBird));
    var removeBirds = SKAction.removeFromParent();
    moveAndRemoveBirds = SKAction.sequence([moveBirds, removeBirds]);

    var spawnBirds = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnBird()})
    var delayBirds = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(4.0))
    var spawnThenDelayBirds = SKAction.sequence([spawnBirds, delayBirds])
    var spawnThenDelayForeverBirds = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelayBirds)
    self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForeverBirds)

    var scoreTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "contactNode")
    scoreTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    contact = SKSpriteNode(texture: scoreTexture1)
    contact.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 3.3, y: self.frame.size.height / 2.2 )
    contact.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1, 800))
    contact.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory
    contact.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = crowCategory
    contact.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    contact.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    contact.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    self.addChild(contact)

    score = 0
    scoreLabelNode.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
    scoreLabelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.6, y: self.frame.size.height / 1.2 )
    scoreLabelNode.fontSize = 40
    scoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.7
    scoreLabelNode.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
    scoreLabelNode.zPosition = -30
    scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(score)"
    self.addChild(scoreLabelNode)

}

func spawnBird() {
    var bird = SKSpriteNode()
    bird.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + birdTexture1.size().width * 2, 0 );
    var height = UInt32( self.frame.size.height / 1 )
    var height_max = UInt32( 500 )
    var height_min = UInt32( 300 )
    var y = arc4random_uniform(height_max - height_min + 1) + height_min;
    var bird1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture1)
    bird1.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y))
    bird1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bird1.size)
    bird1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    bird1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = crowCategory
    bird1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = scoreCategory
    bird1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = scoreCategory
    bird.addChild(bird1)

    bird.runAction(moveAndRemoveBirds)

    birds.addChild(bird)

}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if( moving.speed > 0 ) {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == crowCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == scoreCategory {

            score++
            scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(score)"


        }else {

            //code removed
        }

    }

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

}
}
```

Comment: Does your code pass the `if` to do the `score++`? What's the `contact.bodyA` and `contact.bodyB` `categoryBitMask` if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100 % sure, but you should change these two things :

- " contact.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 " to " contact.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = crowCategory"
- And Make your physicsbodies Dynamic.

"The dynamic property controls whether a volume-based body is affected by gravity, friction, collisions with other objects, and forces or impulses you directly apply to the object. "

Edit:
Also, you want to change:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == crowCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == scoreCategory {
```

to

```
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == crowCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == scoreCategory) || 
(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == scoreCategory  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == crowCategory)
```

That is because you can't know for sure that bodyA always will be the crowCategory. this way you make sure that the IF an object of crowCategory and an object from scoreCategory collide, the score will increase.

Good luck